# Zend Framework Active Directory authentication

Tags: authentication, zend-framework, active-directory

I have received applications written in Zend Framework 1.0.1. User authentication was reportedly taken using Active Directory. Now, to get into the application I used to workaround giving domain and user name:
**DPCAuthAdapter.php file**

```
public function __construct(Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract $db, $userlogin = null) {

    $this->_db=$db;

    $userlogin = 'PFD\\User2'; 

    if((null !== $userlogin) && (strpos($userlogin,'\\') > 0)) {
        list($this->_domain,$this->_username) = explode('\\',strtolower($userlogin),2);
    }
}
```

Without this application does not start.
I have never used the domain user authentication. Please, tips on how I can do it, what to do, how to approach it.

Comment: Happy coding. If you cant search [manual][http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.auth.adapter.ldap.htm] I dont know, you accomplish this.

Comment: LDAP in Zend 1.0.1 version didn`t exist.

Comment: Well you have to upgrade the framework, backport ldap yourself or find any ldap library and use it in your zf 1.0.1 app. And btw. zf 1.0.1 has many bugs and security issues.

Comment: I cant`t upgrade Framework. It not depends on me.